# Sort longtext as int in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I have table in MySQL database where one column type is longtext and there are stored numbers. I need to get content from table sorted by numbers in that column.

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating_avg' ORDER BY meta_value
```

With this query sorting is not proper and looks like:

```
0
1.6
10
5
```

but I need like this:

```
10
5
1.6
0
```

I may not change column type, because this column have many different types of data. Is there any possibility to change column type temporary in SQL query?

Answer (score 10):

What you are looking for is [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast).

```
CAST(expr AS type)
```

Your SQL Query should look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating_avg' ORDER BY CAST(`meta_value` AS DECIMAL) DESC
```

Comment: I have tried this and it works for about first 100 rows in database... After first 100 rows, sorting continues like sorting text.

Comment: well, obviousely there's something wrong with your database/query, and not the solutuion itself.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be accomplished through native WordPress functions without having to resort to raw SQL. Give WP_Query an orderby parameter of `meta_value_num` rather than `meta_value` ([reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)).

Answer (score 0):

It's been over a year since the question was asked, but for reference to anyone that came here after the search, the answer is

> CAST(`meta_value` AS DECIMAL(10,2))

so the query should be:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'rating_avg' ORDER BY CAST(`meta_value` AS DECIMAL(10,2)) DESC
```