# mysql order not working at all

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query which is driving me insane:

```
$getLowestPriceN = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * 
                                       FROM $table 
                                       WHERE post_id = '$post->post_id' 
                                         AND meta_key = '_wholesale_price' 
                                       ORDER BY meta_value ASC ");
```

I am trying to order the results by "meta_value" all meta value are numeric. It doesn't matter if I change this from ASC to DESC, absolutely nothing changes.

Can anyone see anything wrong with the above?

#### EDIT:

The data is stored in the default wordpress postmeta table. I'm sure this answers a few people's questions.

#### EDIT 2:

I have now tried the following:

```
$getLowestPriceN = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE post_id = '$post->post_id' AND meta_key = '_wholesale_price' ORDER BY CAST('meta_value' AS DECIMAL) ASC");

foreach ( $getLowestPriceN as $postN ){
    
    $price = $postN->meta_value;
    
}

return $price
```

This still does not order the results accending...

Comment: what is the column type of `meta_value`? post a couple of sample records

Comment: One thing that is wrong with it is that you are not using prepared statements.

Comment: Also, `WHERE post_id = '$post->post_id'` won't work. It should be `WHERE post_id = '{$post->post_id}'` or `WHERE post_id = '" . $post->post_id . "'`.

Comment: @gbtimmon: They are parametrising a table name, though, that would require dynamic SQL anyway.

Comment: why must everyone always use prepared statementS?

Comment: @AndriyM You parametize the table name before preparing, set the table id after preparing. The table bname is supplied by the application the Id is supplied by the user. Then you are still injection safe.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Because it's 100% resilient against SQL injection! Plus, it's the way of the future :-D

Comment: @jcolebrand http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @RocketHazmat yes, well, no. that's just a reason to use it. Not why everyone MUST use it. When it's RAD the use of raw is fine. When it's production you should use prepared statements.

Comment: *‘Im sure this answers a few people’* – and the others should sit and guess? Or are you only interested in hearing opinions of those who are acquainted with WordPress? I'm fine with that, it's just that it would be fair if you said that straight away.

Comment: @gbtimmon http://dba.stackexchange.com/users/171/jcolebrand You were saying?

Comment: @jcolebrand ...  right, because DBA's are soooo good with application development ... But quippy replies to other quippy replies aside -- if you are a DBA, than you should already know the answer to your question 1.) It's safer. 2.) it runs faster on the DBs (pushing complilation to the application and reducing volume traveling over the wire) 3.) It makes for easier to maintian and easier to write code for the application. I challenge you to give me an example where it would not be the prefered solution thats not convoluted.

Comment: @gbtimmon: As an aside, you might not have been aware but there's no reason to presume a DBA.SE user is necessarily (purely) a DBA, *even though* they are a mod there. The site's scope is slightly wider than that.

Comment: I did give the perfect example already in the comments. As someone who knows both how to code (see this site's rep) and how to manage databases and tune queries for optimum results, I don't need you to tell me all the obvious ways that prepared statements make sense. What I do need, however, is for people to focus on the question that was asked and not focus on the thousand side ideas that could be happening. Next you're gonna tell OP to leave WP and goto Joomla or something.

Comment: @AndriyM jcole's comment was dismissive and rude, refering to some sense of supposed 'authority' rather then make any worthwhile arguments, I simply replied in kind. That was the point I was trying to make by following that with my statement on quippy replies.

Comment: @jcolebrand your rep grants you no authority I judge people on the merit of their argument and you have made none except to say there are some nameless exceptions -- which goes without saying -- There always are. Lets default to best practices and leave exceptions to what we know to be exceptional cases. If the OP had a good reason the not use prepared statements then he certainly would already know to ignore my comment. However if he does not already he should start with prepared statements. And the comments area is for 'comments' not 'answers'  so i dont see my comment as quite that harmful.

Comment: @danyo - [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865081/sort-longtext-as-int-in-sql) may help you. One answer uses a cast, like I proposed. Another proposes using the `WP_Query` function and specifying `meta_value_num` as the "orderby" parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$getLowestPriceN = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * 
                                   FROM `$table` 
                                   WHERE post_id = '$post->post_id' 
                                     AND meta_key = '_wholesale_price' 
                                   ORDER BY meta_value ASC ");
```

try now, may be it works with those `` around the $table

or try

```
$post_id = $post->post_id;
$getLowestPriceN = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * 
                                   FROM `$table` 
                                   WHERE post_id = '$post_id' 
                                     AND meta_key = '_wholesale_price' 
                                   ORDER BY meta_value ASC ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If `meta_value` is a numeric value in a char/varchar column, then (a) bad idea and (b) you can order it numerically by using [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html).

If all the numbers are integers you can cast as `SIGNED`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE post_id = whatever
  AND meta_key = '_wholesale_price'
ORDER BY CAST(meta_value AS SIGNED)
```

If some or all of the numbers will have decimals (likely with something named `_wholesale_price`) you need to cast to `DECIMAL`:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE post_id = whatever
  AND meta_key = '_wholesale_price'
ORDER BY CAST(meta_value AS DECIMAL(12, 2))
```

The `DECIMAL(12,2)` in the example is a guess; if your value can be larger (or have more than 2 decimal places) you'll need to change the cast type accordingly.